# Rails Heroku error of bundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler

After pushed and precompile assets, with I go to my app I have an error.

When I see the logs I have this " `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "rs_reputations" does not exist` "

For this new version I installed a new gem 'reputations', and everything is working perfectly in local.
I tried to run `Heroku run bundle install` but there was no change.

I probably done something wrong, somebody can help me ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't run migration on production server. Run:

```
heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate
```